# Ubuntu server 22.04.3 installation stuck

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04

I tried to install Ubuntu server 22.04.3 at i5 13500 on MSI B760M-P motherboard and it stuck at the exact moment.

It stops progressing after message `r8169 0000:03:00.0 enp3s0: renamed from eth0`

I disabled both fast and secure boot. I re-generated the install media. It all didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Same cpu. MSI z790. Any luck on your end?

Comment: Found a solution. Add ibt=off and nomodeset to your kernel parameters in grub launch.